# Unity 2D collision detector not working

Tags: c#, unity, 2d

I'm making a 2D sidescrolling game in Unity where the player shoots at obstacles while running. But nothing I try seems to get the collision detection to work. This is the obstacle script:

```
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "circle")
                    Destroy (gameObject);
    }
```

the circle tag refers to the projectile being shot at the obstacle

Answer (score 1):

It should be void OnCollisionEnter2D(){}
And if that's not the case (if you just mistyped that here) Make sure you have a rigid-body attached to one of your game objects and make sure both colliding objects have 2d colliders.

Cheers, 
Demetry Romanowski